# Configuration issues when using rust-analyzer from counsel-tramp

Tags: lsp-mode, rust

I have local MacOS(intel) machine running with emacs 27.2 and remote ubuntu 20.0 server for my personal Rust project development with rust-analyzer for lsp.

When I ssh remotely and start emacs on the remote machine, rust-analyzer works fine, but when I start emacs on the local machine and edit the Rust project file after ssh using council-tramp, the following message appears and does not work:

[image]

Also, here is my `lsp-mode` setting below which is inspired by [official documentation](https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-rust-analyzer/#tramp-example):

```
(use-package lsp-mode
   :hook ((rust-mode c++-mode) . lsp)
   :bind ("C-c h" . lsp-describe-thing-at-point)
   :config
   (lsp-register-client
    (make-lsp-client :new-connection (lsp-tramp-connection "rust-analyzer")
                     :major-modes '(rust-mode)
                     :remote? t
                     :server-id 'rust-analyzer-remote))
   (add-to-list 'tramp-remote-path "~/.cargo/bin/")
   :custom
   (lsp-rust-server 'rust-analyzer)
   (lsp-rust-analyzer-cargo-watch-command "clippy")
   (lsp-rust-analyzer-inlay-hints-mode t)
   (lsp-rust-analyzer-server-display-inlay-hints t)
   (lsp-rust-analyzer-display-parameter-hints t)
   (lsp-rust-analyzer-display-chaining-hints t))
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is some questions with `lsp-tramp-connection`, see this [pr](https://github.com/emacs-lsp/lsp-mode/pull/2531)

TLDR:

1. update tramp to 2.5.0
2. use this `lsp-tramp-connection`

```lisp
  (defun lsp-tramp-connection@override (local-command &optional generate-error-file-fn)
    "Create LSP stdio connection named name.
LOCAL-COMMAND is either list of strings, string or function which
returns the command to execute."
    (defvar tramp-connection-properties)
    (list :connect (lambda (filter sentinel name environment-fn)
                     ;; Force a direct asynchronous process.
                     (add-to-list 'tramp-connection-properties
                                  (list (regexp-quote (file-remote-p default-directory))
                                        "direct-async-process" t))
                     (let* ((final-command (lsp-resolve-final-function
                                            local-command))
                            (process-name (generate-new-buffer-name name))
                            (stderr-buf (format "*%s::stderr*" process-name))
                            (err-buf (generate-new-buffer stderr-buf))
                            (process-environment
                             (lsp--compute-process-environment environment-fn))
                            (proc (make-process
                                   :name process-name
                                   :buffer (format "*%s*" process-name)
                                   :command final-command
                                   :connection-type 'pipe
                                   :coding 'no-conversion
                                   :noquery t
                                   :filter filter
                                   :sentinel sentinel
                                   :stderr err-buf
                                   :file-handler t)))
                       (cons proc proc)))
          :test? (lambda () (-> local-command lsp-resolve-final-function
                           lsp-server-present?))))
  (advice-add 'lsp-tramp-connection :override #'lsp-tramp-connection@override)
```